# Iterate object in Handlebars template

Tags: loops, object, ember.js, each, handlebars.js

How can I iterate over an object in a handlebars template within an Ember app?

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>We couldn't create this Company.</strong>
  {{#each errors}          
    <p>{{this}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>

console.log(response.errors);

Object {0: "Name can't be blank", 1: "Zip code can't be blank", 2: "Company type can't be blank", 3: "Address line can't be blank", 4: "Country can't be blank", 5: "State can't be blank"}
```

The error I get in console is:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must
>   be an Array. You passed {0: Name can't be blank, 1: Zip code can't be
>   blank, 2: Company type can't be blank, 3: Address line can't be blank,
>   4: Country can't be blank, 5: State can't be blank}

Any suggestions?

Comment: refactor errors to be an array

Comment: Did you look at my answer below? Would you care to elaborate on how it does or doesn't meet your requirements, since the question is still open?

Answer (score 0):

As your console error states, the `each` helper only works with arrays, so it won't work directly with your `errors` object. You could, however, create a computed property for the `errors` object and inside the property map the object to an array using [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) (or a similar mapping function).

```
errorsArray: function() {
  return $.map(errors, function( value, key ) {
    return value;
  });
}.property('errors')
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, this property will not be updated when properties in `errors` are added, changed, or deleted, unless you call `notifyPropertyChange`.

Comment: @torazaburo, that wasn't a stated requirement, but you're right. There are a significant number of computed property macros that will allow automatic transformations of one sort or another, but nothing I know of that will allow an object to be treated just like an array. An object can behave like an associative array in some ways, but the bottom line is that it's not one. Maybe a `mixin` could be written that would create the necessary `observes` setup, but by the time you've done all that you'd have to wonder why you wouldn't just reshape the model into an array.

Comment: Yes, I was not trying to say that you do not need to reshape the object into an array--you do, in order to `#each` over it. I was merely pointing out that some additional machinery is required to keep the array mapping up to date.